# If storing my API key in an environment variable is unsafe in React, how do I retrieve this key so I can access my endpoints on AWS API Gateway?

Tags: reactjs, aws-api-gateway

My endpoints on AWS API Gateway require that this key be passed in the header in order for the client to successfully my backend endpoint.

Here's my `axios.js` file that sets up the axios instances for GET/POST/PUT/DELETE

```
import axios from 'axios'  
require('dotenv').config()

const API_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_APIGATEWAY_BASE_URL
const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_APIGATEWAY_API_KEY


const AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_URL,  
    headers : {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : API_KEY,
        'X-API-KEY': API_KEY
    }
});

const getAPI = (apiUrl,params) => AxiosInstance.get(apiUrl,params);

const postAPI = (apiUrl, data,params) => AxiosInstance.post(apiUrl, data,params);

const putAPI = (apiUrl, data,params) => AxiosInstance.put(apiUrl, data,params);

const deleteAPI = (apiUrl,data,params) => AxiosInstance.delete(apiUrl,data,params);

export { 
    postAPI,
    getAPI,
    putAPI,
    deleteAPI,
    API_URL
};
export default AxiosInstance;
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your app have users?

If so, you should implement some kind of authentication / authorization logic.

If not, and you allow everyone on the open internet to freely call these api methods, I suppose you can consider building a microservice that will return the `API_KEY` upon request, and store that in the client's storage (`localStorage` on browsers, etc.). The microservice can be implemented through an AWS Lambda Function / Firebase Cloud Function, they're pretty cheap to run, and can obviously use environment variables of their own to retrieve the `API_KEY` from.

Comment: Well the purpose of the API key was so someone doesn't just needlessly hit my endpoint. It can only be triggered by interacting with my website. Having an endpoint that returns the API key doesn't seem to help

Comment: Well, arguably if someone really wanted to "do bad things" by overhitting your endpoint not through a browser, but through a service like Postman, will an unrotated `API_KEY` make a difference? So, I'd say at least implement some kind of a key rotation with each key expiring within a day or something. To me, it's really dangerous if an endpoint can be hit like that, especially if the server logic manipulates a database. Or maybe somehow on the server implement some debouncing / blocking to minimise abuse from a certain IP address. There are a lot of solutions, I suppose.

Comment: It's better than nothing, but not by a lot if your potential attacker are at least a little sophisticated. Maybe not strictly security by obscurity, but not very effective security.